# Python Multiprocessing newbie

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two classes: `class RemeshTweenOnce(object):` and `class RemeshOnce(object):`

Later in the program I have a Function that calls both successively:

`RemesherTweenOnce()`

`RemeshOnce()`

How can I run these two concurrently? I feel that this may be an easy fix, but am very to new to Python and am a bit lost with the documentation.

Comment: The simplest way is to launch 2 processes, 1 of which calls a version of the script that uses `RemesherTweenOnce()`, the other which calls another version of the script which calls `RemeshOnce()`. But it depends on your use-case...if you need it to be more complex than that, describe your usage scenario more.

Answer (score 3):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun1():
    RemesherTweenOnce()

def fun2():
    RemesherOnce()

p1 = Process(target=fun1)
p2 = Process(target=fun2)

# Starts processes.
p1.start()
p2.start()

# If you would like to wait for the results.
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I appreciate the immediate help